# When button is clicked, how to change Button color in Xamarin.Android app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have no idea why the background color doesn't work.

I want to change color when the button is clicked.

This is the screenshot of the problem:
https://gyazo.com/e2b8a9eb269562299bea441c18af4ce0

Comment: Please, next time, copy and paste your code here, don't use screenshots. You can fix that by editing your question it will be more aesthetic and easier for users to help you. Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason for you to use that 'If' statement and that is not OK in any case, as you can see you are getting error also.

You only need to do subscription to the 'Click' event handler. So, remove the 'If' statement, you don't need it!

Your method 'ChangeColorToRed' will be called only when user clicks on that button.

Code for changing background color to red of your button looks like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // ...
    // other code
    // ... 

    ScreenClickButton.Click += ChangeColorToRed;
}

private void ChangeColorToRed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScreenClickButton.SetBackgroundColor(color: Color.Red);
}
```

Wish you good luck with coding!